# setting and getting variable on $scope in controller

Tags: angularjs

Inside the controller of my angular app, I set a scope variable to false like this

```
$scope.stop = false;
```

When I press a button in the UI, I set the $scope.stop value to true inside a function that gets triggered by the button click

```
  $scope.stopRunningThing = function(){
        $scope.stop = true; 
   }
```

Before continuing, I should mention that this already seems like a problem, because I don't know which takes precedence, the $scope.stop in the controller, or inside the function in the controller.

Next, in another function, I do a check to see the value of $scope.stop, however, even though I've set the variable to true inside the function, the code below is always running as if it's always false.

```
if ($scope.stop == true){
    console.log("Never getting run")

}else {
    console.log("always getting run");
}
```

Can you explain how I am supposed to set and check for the value of a variable on $scope in this situation?

Update

$scope.start gets run first in the program and it has a loop that runs forever, and I want the $scope.stop check to run code that breaks out of the loop but the $scope.stop check isn't working as intended

```
   $scope.start = function() {

   ...this check is wrapped in some code that runs continously...
        if ($scope.stop == true){
        console.log("Never getting run")
        ...this is the code that will break out of the continuous code if $scope.stop == true...

       }else {
        console.log("always getting run");

       }

    }
```

Comment: How does your test on `$scope.stop` get fired? You said in a function but how does that function get fired? In theory there is nothing wrong with doing this but it could depend on how that test is getting fired.

Comment: @ShanRobertson it says in the second sentence, `When I press a button in the UI, I set the $scope.stop value to true inside a function that gets triggered by the button click`

Comment: I'm talking about your if statement, `Next, in another function, I do a check to see the value of $scope.stop,`. How is that function called.

Comment: Sounds like some other part of the code might be the issue - here's a fiddle of that code and it seems to do what it should: http://jsfiddle.net/e8boemdn/

Comment: ok sorry, that's actually more complicated. I have a function 'start' that runs some code continuously in a loop, and it does the `if/else` check ( with the code in OP) each time through the loop, so I was hoping when the user presses the stop function (that sets scope to stop), the `if/else` check in the start function would notice the change

Comment: @JamesWaddington see my comment directly above, which might be the issue

Comment: I provided an update in the OP

Comment: Are `start`, `stop` and `stopRunningThing` defined in different scopes?

Comment: @zeroflagL $scope.start and $scope.stopRunningThing are functions defined in the controller scope, $scope.stop is a variable in the same controller.

Comment: It may be important that I am doing the `if($scope.stop == true)` check inside a closure inside the `stopRunningThing` function. does that potentially cut it off from getting the $scope.stop value?